# Airflow error when setting up a beeline Hive connection

Tags: hive, airflow, beeline

I'm trying to create a connection through the Airflow UI but getting an UI error when trying to save it: "Failed to update record. Incorrect padding"

Connection details are:

- Conn Id: `beeline_default`
- Conn Type: `Hive Client Wrapper`
- Host: `fully.qualified.hostname.com`
- Login: `user_with_access_to_hive`
- Password: `some_password`
- Port: `6789`
- Schema: `default;transportMode=http;httpPath=gateway/default/hive;ssl=true;`
- Extra: `{ "use_beeline": true }`

Notes:

- I'm aware the Schema parameter includes more than just the schema, this does not seem to be the problem since (see next);
- Once I remove the `{ "use_beeline": true }` I'm able to save the connection.

Can't see any meaningful messages in the webserver logs, or I might be searching the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to setting up a ssh connection. The details to solve it are:

1. pip install cryptography
2. from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
3. print(Fernet.generate_key().decode())
4. Add the generated key to the config file airflow.cfg

[Source with the issue](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/airflow-commits/201801.mbox/%3CJIRA.13128871.1515174724000.583529.1515174960159@Atlassian.JIRA%3E)